# How to stop the Subscriber in RxAndroid?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I create an Observable like this:

```
public Observable<FileObjectModel> getAllFiles() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<FileObjectModel>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super FileObjectModel> subscriber) {
            //fileList is a huge list.
            for(int i = 1 ; i < fileList.size(); i ++){
                ...
                subscriber.onNext(fileItem);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

then subscribe like this:

```
subscription = reposistory.getAllFiles()
            .compose(scanInject())
            .subscribe(...);
```

When user click button stop, I want to cancel the subscription, so I call

```
 subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't stop as expected. The file items are continue emitted.

Please help to point out my mistake.

**UPDATE:**

I debug line by line and see that the observable is being stuck in `for` loop. In this loop, I call a recursive method and pass subscriber as parameter. The method will browse all Android File System (start at root folder) to find all files, then emit them one by one.  (I use this way because the number of file on entire system is very large, and shouldn't save in any static list. )
Since we are being stuck in `for` loop, the subscription object is always null. Still don't find any solution yet.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `Observable.from(fileList)`?  Conventional wisdom is you should avoid `Observable.create` if possible as it's very easy to get wrong

Comment: fileList is provide by recursively methods to get all files inside Android File System. It's mean we don't have the full list at starting time, I have to pass subscriber along recursively method to emit data.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly if you are going to use `Observable.create` then to honour backpressure which is required by many possible downstream operators you need to append `.onBackpressureXXX`. If in doubt just use `.onBackpressureBuffer`.

The reason you cannot unsubscribe is because your observable is synchronous so the `subscription` is not set till the stream has finished! I'd suggest avoiding this pattern generally and use instead:

```
subscriber = ...;
reposistory.getAllFiles()
    .compose(scanInject())
    .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: All `onBackPressurexxx` are not satisfy my case. I can't use `xxxxDrop` or similar because I don't want to omit any files. `xxxxBuffer` will cause Out of memory issue since the number of items are very very large.
I already apply your suggestion, now how to stop/pause it?

Comment: Dave, in your suggested way, how to stop the subscription ?

Comment: subscriber.unsubscribe()

Comment: see my answer below. That's my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if the subscriber is still subscribed:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < fileList.size(); i ++){
    if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    }
    subscriber.onNext(fileItem);
}
```

This should not be too much computation overload.

Answer (score 0):

*I hate to answer my question anyway, but I already found the root cause and action to fix it.*

As I mentioned in **update** part of my question, the `for` loop did a huge job, it iterated thousand of items. And, the processor was being stuck inside.

To fix this, I assign the different threads to observable and it runs  asynchronous, like this:

```
 subscription = getAllObjects()
            .map(this::doScan)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
```

The variable `subscription` now never `null` as before and we can use it to stop the subscriptions by calling `subscription.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Yep making the observable asynchronous solveso your problem but I already explained that in my answer.